# External keyboard inserting characters when typing fast

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut

I'm using a [Kinesis Freestyle2 Blue](https://kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle2-mac/) keyboard with my 2019 MacBook Pro,  and I'm experiencing some strange behavior. With the <kbd>fn</kbd> key activated, the key combination `cd`, when typed quickly, causes Launchpad to open (which, on my computer, is linked to <kbd>F12</kbd>). Other key combinations also cause strange behavior in a similar fashion. With the <kbd>fn</kbd> key deactivated, `cd` doesn't open Launchpad, but when typed in the Terminal it causes the screen to flash and the terminal to emit a bell.

Some other weird behavior: `vf` => `vfg`, `xs` => `xs§`, `mj` => `mhj`, `qa` => `qa`<kbd>tab</kbd>

What's causing this strange behavior?

Comment: What Operating System are you running?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist Catalina

Answer (score 1):

Get hold of [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store, so you can test what the keyboard is actually outputting.

If it's sending garbage, then you'd probably need to speak to the manufacturer.